# Gulp: moving and converting background-images url correctly using gulp + stylus + images from sub folders?

Tags: css, gulp, stylus

How do we move certain files from subfolders and convert background-images url correctly using gulp + stylus + images from sub folders? Also, if i were to remove a image, I would need to have the image be removed from the dist/...

Ex
source /images/X/Y/Z/abc.png
dist /images/abc.png

main.styl

```
background-image url('../images/X/Y/Z/abc.png')
```

main.css - this is what I'm looking for:

```
background-image url('../images/abc.png')
```

I DO NOT want to get this in my after gulp processed by css:

```
background-image url('../images/X/Y/Z/abc.png')
```

Appreciate the help Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing off the top of my head something like this, but you could run into issues with files of the same name but in different directories:

```
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('images', function() {
  del(['./dist/images/*']);
  gulp.src('./images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}').pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/images'));
});
```

As for your CSS/SASS source file, you will just use the final URL path instead of the unprocessed URL path.